Find non-zero polynomials $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ with integer coefficients such that $(n^2+3)f(n)^2+1=g(n)^2$
Find non-zero polynomials $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ with integer coefficients such that $(n^2+3)f(n)^2+1=g(n)^2$.
This problem comes from Pell's equation, which states that for $\forall m\in\mathbb{N}^*$, where $m$ is not a square, there exist positive integer solutions for the equation $x^2-my^2=1$. I was trying to prove this starting with some special cases.
First I deal with a special case where $m=n^2+1$ for an arbitrary positive integer $n$. Then I come up with a quite simple solution. Consider the identity $(2n^2+1)^2-(n^2+1)(2n)^2=1$, which has already been an integer solution where $x=2n^2+1$ and $y=2n$.
Second I deal with the case where $m=n^2+2$. The solution is even much easier with the identity $(n^2+1)^2-(n^2+2)n^2=1$.
However, things become complicated when $m=n^2+3$. Using the same strategy before, it's equivalent to finding non-zero polynomials $\displaystyle f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^ka_in^i$ and $\displaystyle g(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}b_in^i$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with integer coefficients such that $(n^2+3)f(n)^2+1=g(n)^2$.
My attempt First, let $n=1$. We have $4f(1)^2+1=g(1)^2$, which implies $\displaystyle |2f(1)|<|g(1)|<\max\{|2f(1)+1|,|2f(1)-1|\}$ if $f(1)\neq 0$. Since the coefficients of $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are all integers, it leads to a contradiction. Therefore, we can conclude that $f(1)=0$ and $g(1)=±1$. Similarly, let $n=-1$, and we have $f(-1)=0$ and $g(-1)=±1$. This implies both $1$ and $-1$ are roots of $f(n)$ and therefore $k\geq 2$. But this doesn't seem to be helpful enough.
Second, I try to deal with cases when $k$ is not large, e.g., $k=2$ or $k=3$.
When $k=2$, \begin{aligned} &(n^2+3)(a_2 n^2+a_1 n+a_0)^2-(b_3 n^3+b_2 n^2+b_1n+b_0)^2+1\\=&n^6(a_2^2-b_3^2)+n^5(2 a_1 a_2-2b_2b_3)+n^4(a_1^2+3a_2^2+2a_0a_2-b_2^2-2b_1b_3) \\+&n^3(2a_0 a_1+6a_2a_1-2(b_1 b_2+b_0b_3))+n^2(a_0^2+6a_2a_0+3a_1^2-b_1^2-2b_0b_2) \\+&n(6 a_0 a_1-2b_0b_1)+3a_0^2-b_0^2+1.\end{aligned} The above calculation result comes from Mathematica. I try to let all coefficients be zero, but I find that there even don't exist REAL numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3$ such that $\left(n^2+3\right)\left(a_2 n^2+a_1 n+a_0\right)^2-\left(b_3 n^3+b_2 n^2+b_1 n+b_0\right)^2+1\equiv 0$.
When $k=3$,
\begin{aligned}
& (n^2+3)(a_3n^3+a_2n^2+a_1n+a_0)^2-(b_4n^4+b_3n^3+b_2n^2+b_1n+b_0)^2+1 \\
=& n^8(a_3^2-b_4^2)+n^7(2a_2a_3-2b_3b_4)+n^6(a_2^2+3a_3^2+2a_1a_3-b_3^2-2b_2b_4) \\ +&2n^5(a_1a_2+3a_3a_2+a_0a_3-b_2b_3-b_1b_4) \\+&n^4(a_1^2+6a_3a_1+3a_2^2+2a_0a_2-b_2^2-2b_1b_3-2b_0b_4) \\
+&n^3(6a_1a_2+2a_0(a_1+3a_3)-2(b_1b_2+b_0b_3))
+n^2(a_0^2+6a_2a_0+3a_1^2-b_1^2-2b_0b_2) \\+&n(6a_0a_1-2b_0b_1)+3a_0^2-b_0^2+1.
\end{aligned} The result is also that there even don't exist real numbers $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ such that $(n^2+3)(a_3n^3+a_2n^2+a_1n+a_0)^2-(b_4n^4+b_3n^3+b_2n^2+b_1n+b_0)^2+1\equiv 0$.
Therefore, I guess there're no REAL coefficients to form the identity $(n^2+3)f(n)^2+1=g(n)^2$ when $k\geq 2$. I don't know whether my guessing is correct or not.
By the way, I believe that I've successfully proved when $k$ is even, we cannot find such $a_k,a_{k-1},\cdots,a_0,b_{k+1},\cdots,b_0\in\mathbb{R}$. This is because when $k$ is even, $k+1$ is odd. We can rewrite $(n^2+3)f(n)^2+1=g(n)^2$ as $$(n^2+3)\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=0}^ka_in^i\bigg)^2+0.5=\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}b_in^i\bigg)^2-0.5.$$ Obviously, the left hand side is forever positive if $n$ only takes real values, which implies $LHS=0$ does not have real solutions. On the other hand, since $k+1$ is odd, the right hand side$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}b_in^i=\sqrt{0.5}$ always has real number solutions, which implies $RHS=0$ has real solutions. This leads to a contradiction.
However, I cannot get any further when $k$ is odd. Any help will be appreciated.

Just running a computer search up to $\deg(f) = 6150$ (so that $\deg(g) = 6151$) finds no solutions in polynomials with integer coefficients.  (Lots of solutions with complex coefficients...)  So it's plausible that there are no solutions in polynomials with integer coefficients.

Of polynomials with rational coefficients, a solving pair is $f(n) = \frac{2}{3} n$, $g(n) = \frac{2}{3} n^2 + 1$, so there are solutions in real coefficients.  (In fact, there are eight variations of this one solution differing only in the signs of the nonzero coefficients.)

(I miscounted.  There are four variations of the one solution -- the two nonzero coefficients in $g$ are always the same sign.)

But is it possible to find real coefficients when the degree of $k\geq 2$? My original  intention of this problem is to find interger solutions, but then I realize such solutions are only possible when $k\geq 2$. Surprisingly I find that it's even difficult to find real solutions when $k\geq 2$, let alone integer solutions. So I’m more curious for cases of $k\geq 2$.

Perhaps the last post in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1928151p13234261 gives a way to prove this for real polynomials.

The only polynomials $f,g$ with integer coefficients such that $(x^2+3)f(x)^2+1=g(x)^2$ are $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=\pm 1$.
Proof. From $x=1$ we get $(2f(1))^2+1=g(1)^2$, but only perfect squares that differ by $1$ are $0$ and $1$, so $f(1)=0$ and $g(1)=\pm 1$. Similarly, from $x=-1$ we get $f(-1)=0$. Also notice, if $g(x)$ is a solution, $-g(x)$ is also a solution, so WLOG let's $g(1)=1$.
Hence $f(x)=(x^2-1)f_2(x)$ and $g(x)=1+(x-1)g_2(x)$ for some $f_2,g_2\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Plugging back to the original equation we simplify it to
$$
(x^2+3)(x+1)^2(x-1)f_2(x)^2=(x-1)g_2(x)^2+2g_2(x).
$$
So $x-1 \mid g_2(x)$, let $g_2(x)=(x-1)g_3(x)$. Hence
$$
(x^2+3)(x+1)^2f_2(x)^2=(x-1)^2g_3(x)^2+2g_3(x).
$$
For $x=-1$ we now get
$$
0=4g_3(-1)^2+2g_3(-1)=g_3(-1)(4g_3(-1)+2).
$$
Since $g_3(-1)$ is an integer, $4g_3(-1)+2\neq 0$, hence $g_3(-1)=0$. So let $g_3(x)=(x+1)g_4(x)$, then
$$
(x^2+3)(x+1)f_2(x)^2=(x-1)^2(x+1)g_4(x)^2+2g_4(x).
$$
As before we see $x+1\mid g_4(x)$, so $g_4(x)=(x+1)g_5(x)$ and
$$
(x^2+3)f_2(x)^2=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2g_5(x)^2+2g_5(x)
$$
If $f_2\equiv g_5 \equiv 0$, we get the two solutions $f(x)= 0$, $g(x)=\pm 1$. Otherwise, let $h(x)=\gcd(f_2(x),g_5(x))$ and $f_2(x)=h(x)f_3(x)$, $g_5(x)=h(x)g_6(x)$. Then
$$
(x^2+3)h(x)f_3(x)^2=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2h(x)g_6(x)^2+2g_6(x)
$$
Again $h(x)\mid g_6(x)$, i.e. $g_6(x)=h(x)g_7(x)$ and
$$
(x^2+3)f_3(x)^2=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2h(x)^2g_7(x)^2+2g_7(x)
$$
Now $\gcd(g_7(x),f_3(x))=1$ and so $g_7(x)\mid x^2+3$. Thus either $g_7(x)=\pm 1$ or $g_7(x)=\pm(x^2+3)$. But then $x=1$ gives either $(2f_3(1))^2=\pm 2$ or $(2f_3(1))^2=\pm 8$, both impossible.

Can this be generalized to real coefficients? I think it's even impossible to find real coefficients when the degree of $f(x)$ is greater than 2...

Not in this form, the argument uses that $f(n)$ is an integer on several places. You might want to ask another question for real coefficients.
